# the JSLint code quality tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

So I checked my javascript using this: http://www.jslint.com/

and if I don't wrap IF/FOR statements between { }, I get "errors" like this:

> Problem at line 152 character 27:
>   Expected '{' and instead saw
>   'reset()'.

or if I initialize variables inside FOR I get:

> Problem at line 154 character 19: Move
>   'var' declarations to the top of the
>   function.

Why are these considered errors?
Shouldn't these be considered good practice instead because they actually reduce the size of the code, which for javascript is even more important than the speed of the code?

Comment: Why is the size of the code more important for Javascript than the speed of the code?

Comment: @Pekka: Not following you, neither of these examples affects code speed.

Comment: because it doesn't run on the server. And to make a script that lags in the client's computer is very hard considering the speed of the computers of today, so speed becomes less important...

Comment: @T.J. the OP states that the size of the code is more important than its speed. I mean to say I don't think that is true (or don't understand the reasoning behind it)

Comment: @Alexa the size of the code is usually not important for its execution speed - it's definitely not a good paradigm to design code by. Consider that with most HTML pages, you are transferring images dozens or hundreds of times the size of all your JavaScript combined.

Comment: @Pekka: Ah, okay, with you. And agreed, I'd say it was the other way around, since JavaScript interpreters in the wild have tended to be a bit slow *(I'm looking at you, Microsoft)*, I'd rather have the code take an extra few milliseconds to download if it ran faster. :-)

Comment: Crockford proudly states that JSLint will hurt your feelings.

Comment: you're right it doesn't matter, but the same is for speed. In my opinion the size of the js is a little more important than the speed of the js. So if you have a 10K js instead of a 11K js it's better than if you had a js that's 1-5-10% faster :)

Comment: @Rohannes - Which is why it sucks. Crockford takes pride in the fact that people pander to his beliefs. Many of his JSLint rules (the second one above being a prime example) affect code quality in no way. It's just Crockford's opinion on what your code *should* look like, but because it's automated, people think that their code is invalid, when in fact there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Since all variables are declared together at the start of their scope, it reduces the chance of scoping errors (which can be really tricky to debug), thereby improving code quality. It's there to help.

Comment: Given the recent goto fail hack it's a shame that all languages don't enforce braces around if/for statements

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the `if` statement error, the lack of an opening brace is considered bad practice because it makes for harder maintenance. If, for example, you wanted to add another statement inside the if statement, you'd end up needing to add the braces anyway, so it makes maintenance easier just to include them in the first place.

The second error, I find a bit.. opinionated, since personally I prefer to declare variables closer to where they are used, instead of at the top of a function.

Personally, I prefer to use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) these days, since Crockfords Lint I find to be less about correct code, and more about Crockfords opinion of what JavaScript should look like, everyone else's opinion be damned.

Comment: Crockford has increasingly thrust his opinions in JSLint users' faces, and has now gone way too far, in my opinion. The `var` thing is ridiculous, as is labelling all uses of `==` and `!=` as errors without any option to override. JSLint is now unusable as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Now this relieves me! Most of my modular code doesn't pass through JSLint! +1 for JSHint! :D

Answer (score 4):

JSLint recommends that you wrap if and for statements in braces because it can lead to hard to track down errors if you are not careful with your indenting. For example:

```
if (somecondition)
    step1();
    step2();
```

From the indenting, it looks like step1() and step2() are going to execute only if somecondition is true, but in reality step2() will always run since the braces are missing.

If you are really concerned about file size, I'd suggest looking into a JS compressor like yuicompressor. Most of these will remove the braces around if/for statements that don't need them. Then you can have the best of both worlds: readable code and small file sizes when it's served.

Answer (score 3):

Respect tho the second issue, JSlint recommends it because javascript vars are always **function scoped**, not block scoped. Doing this:

```
function func(){
  var i;
  alert('foo');
  for(i = 0; i<3; i++){
     alert(i);
  }
  alert(i);
}
```

is exactly (100% exactly!!) the same as:

```
function func(){
  alert('foo');
  for(var i = 0; i<3; i++){
     alert(i);
  }
  alert(i);
}
```

So `i` is not for-scoped (as in other languages). That's why jslint recommends to put all vars on top of functions, so you don't get confused thinking there are block-scoped variables.

Respect of the first issue, I agree with you. I don't see it as big a problem. But JSLint  sees it as a problem because, if you later add lines to your if statement and forget to put the curly braces, you'll have a logic error, as Jeff pointed out.

Before:

```
if (x > 10)
    alert("it's obvious x is positive");
```

After some changes to the code:

```
if (x > 10)
    alert("it's obvious x is positive");  
    alert("x is greater than 10");  //Logic error
```

A problem that wouldn't have happened using curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

JSLint is a code *quality* tool aimed to reduce the number of mistakes. You know that you can only write a single statement in an if loop, without needing to wrap it with braces, but that guy doesn't. And what if you accidentally do it one day?

Reducing file-size during development is hardly necessary, that's what minifiers are for. During development you need to make the code work and make sense.

The variables at top of functions is an annoying debate of coding styles, and you can turn off notifications about it in the options.

Anyway, just ignore the errors you don't care about.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing, braces on `if` statements, reflects the JSLint author's belief that omitting the braces leads to maintenance issues (a belief I happen to share, but that's neither here nor there).

The second thing is actually language-specific: Putting the `var` anywhere other than the top of the scope (function, or global) is actually misleading to anyone reading the code, because regardless of where you put it, it's *exactly as though* it were at the top of the scope. Details: [*Poor, misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)

Comment: While your point about variable declarations being hoisted is true, I don't think it has to mean you declare all your variables at the top of a function. I prefer to keep the declaration of a variable as close as possible to the first use of the variable for readability, I see no significant problem with doing so and I am confident I'm making an informed choice, so JSLint insisting on it without an option to override makes it essentially unusable for me.

Comment: @Tim: Yeah, I'm not a big fan of lint tools without config options for precisely that reason. (I strongly disagree about `var`, but that's just style; keep your functions short enough and it doesn't really matter anyway.) Another of my favorites from JSLint: "'*function_name*' was used before it was defined". It just plain gets that wrong, if the function is a *declaration* lower down in the scope. The function *is* defined, unambiguously, and yet it complains anyway...

Comment: J. I've read your blog post about `var` before and fully understand the reasoning, but as you say there, there's no absolute right and wrong. Your objection to the "function was used before it was defined" thing is curious to me though: using a function before its declaration is getting further from expressing what's really happening (hoisting), and therefore seems pretty much identical to the `var` thing to me.

Comment: @Tim: I see what you're saying. I guess for me the distinction is the expectation. I've never seen anyone confused by a function being called before it was declared, probably because the majority of modern languages work that way. I've seen several people confused by the `var` thing, though, and seen bugs caused by it. Hence my "throw Michael a bone" in the blog post. :-) Again, though, keep functions short and there really isn't much in it either way.

Answer (score 0):

You ask: "Why are these considered errors?" They're much more than bad practice; they're positively malicious. That's because they encourage later bugs that will be almost impossible to find. This same death-wish omission of braces is allowed in C and C++, too, and it's just as much of an error there.

If, like me, you'd tried to save a couple of keystrokes by omitting braces and then been bitten and beaten up by your mistake, I promise you wouldn't be asking this question :-)

Comment: Braces, fully agreed. All variables to be declared at the top: subjective. Valid arguments exist for both sides of that particular argument. Insisting on it without an option to override is one of JSLint's many flaws.